# Sort Array based on an bother array from minimum to maximum value

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I'm using this code to sort an Array

```
Array.Sort(numsFoundedCount, numsFoundedSorted);
```

Which it works but when 2 items of numsFoundedSorted have the same numsFoundedCount value i want them (the numsFoundedSorted items) to be sorted from min to max.

```
int[] numsFoundedCount = new int[80];
int[] numsFoundedSorted = new int[80];
```

**numsFoundedSorted** inludes an integer and **numsFoundedCount** represent how many times this integer has appear. so i want to sort numsFoundedSorted from minumum to maximum according to numsFoundedCount.

I want both of the arrays to be sorted like in Array.Sort
For example:

```
numsFoundedSorted {5,7,6,8}
numsFoundedCount {3,2,2,1}
```

After sort must be:

```
numsFoundedSorted {8,6,7,5}
numsFoundedCount {1,2,2,3}
```

Comment: can you give us more details about the definitions of `numsFoundedCount` and `numsFoundedSorted`?

Comment: its a simple int[] array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood right, this is what you want

```
var numsFoundedSorted = numsFoundedSorted
    .Select((item, idx) => new { Index = idx, Value = item })
    .OrderBy(tuple => numsFoundedCount[tuple.Index])
    .ThenBy(tuple => tuple.Value)
    .Select(tuple => tuple.Value)
    .ToArray();

Array.Sort(numsFoundedCount);
```

There is no options to do it with `Array.Sort`

And if you are already using C# 7 features you can replace `new { Index = idx, Value = item }` with `(Index: idx, Value: item)`

Comment: I guess this will only sort numsFoundedSorted array. to also sort numsFoundedCount all i have to do after your code is Array.Sort(numsFoundedCount); Also will your code sort numsFoundedSorted items from min to max? cause i see on OrderBy you have set numsFoundedCount

Comment: `ThenBy(tuple => tuple.Value)` this line here makes the sorting of `numsFoundedSorted` by value from min to max in case of equivalent value of numsFoundedCount in same position. And yes, this code just sorts numsFoundedSorted